# Same MKOverlayView delegate called in one UIView but not another. What's missing?

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, overlay, mkpolyline

My app tracks GPS movement as a MKPolyline routepath on a MKMapView as an MKOverlayRenderer in the HomeVC, saves the data, and displays it later, as a saved routepath a few VCs deeper, on DisplayVC.  I can confirm that the data is identical to the original data on the second VC, and the proper routeBounds are used when the map is shown, but the OverlayRenderer is never called on the second VC.  Why not?  I'm thinking delegate problems, but I can't find anything wrong.

Both homeVC.h

```
@interface homeVC : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
```

and displayVC.h   are the same, except for the name:

```
@interface displayVC : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,  MKMapViewDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager   *locationManager;
    //  the data representing the route points
    MKPolyline*     _routePath;
    //  the view we create for the line on the map
    MKPolylineView* _routePathVw;
    //  the rect that bounds the loaded points
    MKMapRect       _routeBounds;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView   *mapView;
@end
```

And both homeVC.m and displayVC.m are set up the same:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //  Add the Map
    [_mapView setDelegate:self];
    _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
}
```

Lots of good-working code here.  Then,

```
-(void) buildRoute {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  thisCoord;
    int i = [arrayLa count] - 1;    //  keep growing the array size
    MKMapPoint  *tmpArr = realloc(pointArr, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*(arrayLa.count));
    pointArr = tmpArr;
    thisCoord.latitude  = [[arrayLa objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    thisCoord.longitude = [[arrayLo objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    MKMapPoint  point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(thisCoord);
    pointArr[i] = point;
    // Reset Map View Boundaries
    if( point.x > ne_Pt.x - 500 )    ne_Pt.x = point.x + 1000;
    if( point.y > ne_Pt.y - 500 )    ne_Pt.y = point.y + 1000;
    if( point.x < sw_Pt.x + 500 )    sw_Pt.x = point.x - 1000;
    if( point.y < sw_Pt.y + 500 )    sw_Pt.y = point.y - 1000;
    // create the polyline based on the C-array of map Points
    _routePath = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:arrayLa.count];
    _routeBounds = MKMapRectMake(sw_Pt.x, sw_Pt.y, ne_Pt.x-sw_Pt.x, ne_Pt.y-sw_Pt.y);
    // add the routePath overlay to the map, if it isn't empty
    if (recState == REC && _routePath != nil) {
        // zoom in on the route with the fresh bounding box, routeBounds
        [self zoomInOnRoute];
        [_mapView addOverlay:_routePath];
    }
}

-(void) zoomInOnRoute {
    [_mapView setVisibleMapRect:_routeBounds];
}

#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3;
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return routeRenderer;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Can anyone help solve my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a delegate issue.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the addOverLay call just in case the 'if' is skipping it?

I do something similar and all works fine using MKOverlay and MKOverlayRender (based on the apple  Breadcrumbs sample app but updated).  The app displays a route that the user can save to CoreData.  They can select from a table of saved routes and the route is rendered using MKOverlayRenderer.

Set the delegate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
}
```

Create a MKOverlay and add to mapView

```
- (void)createRoute2
{
    // Some CoreData stuff.  Iterate through map points and create an overlay.
    // Order by date ascending so we draw in sequential order
    NSSortDescriptor *timeStampDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pointDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[timeStampDescriptor];
    NSArray *routePts = [[self.selectedRoute mapDetail] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    // A long is a bit excessive just use an int is fine ( BUT might be a huge number of route points)
    long nbrPts = routePts.count;

    if (nbrPts < 2){
        return;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapPointLoc;
    MKMapRect updateRect; // The map area

    // Init the route
    // FtfmapDetail is a managed object holding lat long (and other stuff)
    FtfMapDetail *currentPt = (FtfMapDetail *)[routePts objectAtIndex:0];
    mapPointLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([currentPt.latitude floatValue], [currentPt.longitude floatValue]);
    // self.route is a subclassed MapOverlay
    if (!self.route)
    {
        // BGSMapOverlay is a subclassed MapOverlay
        self.route = [[BGSMapOverlay alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:mapPointLoc];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.route];
    }

    // Add subsequent points.  Kick off the for loop at int position 1 not 0
    for (int i=1; i <nbrPts; i++){

        currentPt = (FtfMapDetail *)[routePts objectAtIndex:i];
        mapPointLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([currentPt.latitude floatValue], [currentPt.longitude floatValue]);
        // AddCoordinate is a method in MKOverlay subclass that returns a bounding MKMaprect for all points in MkOverlay
        updateRect = [self.route addCoordinate:mapPointLoc];
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(self.route.boundingMapRectCompleteRoute);

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

And make sure you add the delegate method

```
#pragma mark - MKMapView delegate

// self.routeViewRenderer is a sub-classed MKOverlayRendered (based on the Breadcrumbs app from apple CrumbPathView subclassed MKOverlayView)
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    if (!self.routeViewRenderer)
    {
        _routeViewRenderer = [[BGSMKOverlayRender alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    }
    return self.routeViewRenderer;

}
```

Or it could be that you are not sending any coordinates to the MkPolyLine.  In the following snippet if I uncomment the "NSArray *routeCoordinates = [[NSArray alloc]init];" to send a Nil array to the MKPolyLine then the code will run but the delegate doesn't get called.  If routeCoordinates contains points then delegate is called and route displayed.

```
-(void)buildRouteOverlays
{
    for (int i=0; i< _routeHeaders.count;i++)
    {
        _selectedRoute = (FtfMaps*) [_routeHeaders objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"DEBUG route date : %@", _selectedRoute.dateMap);
        NSArray *routeCoordinates = [self arrayRoutePointCoordinates];
        // if a nil array is produce then MapOverlayRenerder is not called - nothing to render
        // Test this by uncommenting:
        // NSArray *routeCoordinates = [[NSArray alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"DEBUG number of point in Route : %lu",(unsigned long)routeCoordinates.count);
        // Just a quick test only process the first route
        if (i==0){
            MKPolyline *routePolyLine = [self polyLineFromArray:routeCoordinates];
            [self.mapView addOverlay:routePolyLine];
        }
    }
}

-(MKPolyline*)polyLineFromArray:(NSArray*)routePoints
{
    NSInteger pointsCount = routePoints.count;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        FtfMapDetail *mapPt = (FtfMapDetail *) [routePoints objectAtIndex:i];
        pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([mapPt.latitude doubleValue], [mapPt.longitude doubleValue]);
    }
    MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:pointsCount];
    return myPolyline;

}


#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3;
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return routeRenderer;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had an NSLog before the if() which never executed.

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer - maybe you're not sending any points to the polyLine? Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, again, but I'm sure that all of the points are correctly in the route.